# Javascript No. of File attached

Tags: javascript, forms, attachment

It works fine with Google Chrome and Mozilla... But does not work correctly with Internet Explorer.

```
var col = document.getElementById('myFormid');
var fields = col.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(x in fields){
if(fields[x].name == 'doc[]' && fields[x].value != ''){
files++;    
}
}
```

Comment: You could use [`.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) instead of `.getElementsByTagName()` - That would save you the first if condition.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays, as you will access the array's prototype methods along with its elements. Just use the regular `for` syntax and see if that helps:

```
var col = document.getElementById('myFormid');
var fields = col.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  var field = fields[i];

  if ((field.name == 'doc[]') && (field.value != '')) {
    files++;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Blender It Would be a great favour. If You look at this Link http://bit.ly/R9TdA6 I am Getting Javascript Problem with the File attachments section made at bottom of the page. This Code Works Fine with Google Crome and IE but With Mozilla it is giving Problems.. Please Help Sir. Please open it in mozilla.

Comment: You are loading `menu.js` *before* `jquery.js`, which is causing problems. Move `menu.js` after the `jquery.js` `<script>` tags.